# How to install mongoDB on Bitnami WAMP (windows) for using with symfony 3?

Tags: windows, mongodb, symfony, bitnami

How to install mongoDB on Bitnami WAMP (windows) for using with symfony 3 ?

Windows 10, x64.

php PHP 5.6.20 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2016 14:56:44).

I have tried mongodb releases from 1.1.1 to 1.1.8
from http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

I managed to download and install mongodb on windows. But i am not able to use it with WAMP and symfony.

This question is a bit changed, because i managed to get working php_mongodb.dll.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "mongodb/mongodb" : "dev-master", 
    "doctrine/mongodb": "dev-master",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.1",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0",
```

The current problem is

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.3 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.4 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.5 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

The previous problem was, that i could not run php if i installed php_mongodb as described below. I resolved ths by installing Bitnami MEAN stack and copyong php_mongo.dll and php_mongodb.dll to Bitnami WAMP php/exy folder.

1) WINDOWS  installation (working) – 
1) download msi from :
https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/
Remember where DB is installed – on , and
Add this path to system variables : C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

run cmd: mongod

Create a folder for your database files, for example on  C:\Bitnami\mongodb
and run command
c:\Users\gintare>mongod --dbpath C:\Bitnami\mongodb

This will create a database in the folder.

2) Symfony installation (does not work)
composer.json

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/mongodb": "dev-master",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.1",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0",
```

2a) I followed the steps 
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows
Downloaded  `mongodb.dll 1.8.8` from
http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb
unzipped to:
`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\ext\php_mongodb-1.1.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x64`
I tried both thread safe and unsafe versions. Both gave the same errors.

and copied file `php_mongodb.dll` to `C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\ext`
and corrected `php.ini` by adding `extension=php_mongodb.dll`. Restarted Apache from Bitnami.

Nevertheless iam getting the  error`Unable to load dynamic library`:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1>php 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.20-0/php/ext\php_mongodb.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

2b) If i try to install using pecl, i am getting the error `invalid package`:

```
:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\ext>pecl install mongodb
downloading mongodb-1.1.8.tgz ...
Starting to download mongodb-1.1.8.tgz (806,900 bytes)
.................................................................................................................................................................done: 806,900 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\pear\download\mongodb-1.1.8.tgz"
Download of "pecl/mongodb" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/mongodb"
Download failed
install failed
```

2c) If i try to install mongoDB with composer, i am getting the error `doctrine/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongo ^1.5` .

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1>composer update

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.20-0/php/ext\php_mongodb.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[dev-master].
    - doctrine/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.3 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.4 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.0.5 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1>

        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.1",
```

Comment: I always know that windows is for complicating life, but never know that the complication level is so high.

Comment: Found a blog, trying : http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way

Comment: still do not work (2b) pgp_mongodb installation and (2c) MongoDb installation to Symfony project hosted on Bitnami WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I will start from conclusion: install Bitnami meanstack, learn javascript, node.js, react.js, Docher containers, etc.. and forget Symfony and php.

A) mongodb installation and setup on windows

1) download msi from : https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

2) Remember where DB is installed – on , and add this path to system variables : C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

3) Official mongodb.dll php to mongodb bindings v1.1.1 to 1.1.8 from http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb were not working for me. Thus i installed Bitnami MEAN stack and copied php_mongo.dll and php_mongodb.dll to Bitnami WAMP php/ext folder.

4) Than configured network and services as desribed :

https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/10/install-setup-and-start-mongodb-on-windows/

https://mkmanu.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/solution-trouble-in-listening-port-27017-after-installing-mongodb-on-windows-7-64bit/

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh
netsh>advfirewall firewall
netsh advfirewall firewall> add rule name="Open mongod port 27017" dir=in action=allow protocol=tCP localport=27017
Ok.

netsh advfirewall firewall>add rule name="Allowing mongod" dir=in action=allow program="C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe"
Ok.

netsh advfirewall firewall>add rule name="Allowing mongos" dir=in action=allow program="C:\mongodb\bin\mongos.exe"
Ok.

netsh advfirewall firewall> ctrl+c  (quit this netsh and advfirewall firewall)
```

Now install service:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mongod -f c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1\mongodb.conf  --install --serviceName mongodb27017 --serviceDisplayName "mongodb server instance on port 27017" --serviceDescription "mongoDB server instance running on 27017"
```

use --remove , if you want to delete it.

Start the service you just created (You can also do it from services):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start mongodb27017
The mongodb server instance on port 27017 service is starting.
The mongodb server instance on port 27017 service was started successfully.
```

Start the shell:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
>
```

5) Test the database from the shell

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
> for (var i=1; i<=25; i++) db.testData.insert( {x:i} )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.testData.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271925"), "x" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271926"), "x" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271927"), "x" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271928"), "x" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271929"), "x" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd827192a"), "x" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd827192b"), "x" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd827192c"), "x" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd827192d"), "x" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd827192e"), "x" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd827192f"), "x" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271930"), "x" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271931"), "x" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271932"), "x" : 14 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271933"), "x" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271934"), "x" : 16 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271935"), "x" : 17 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271936"), "x" : 18 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271937"), "x" : 19 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3f53b78fbe7dbd8271938"), "x" : 20 }
Type "it" for more
>
```

6) Test the database from index.php

```
<?php

// http://localhost/index.php
// C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\index.php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//echo get_include_path();
//phpinfo();

// connect
$m = new MongoClient();

// select a database
$db = $m->comedy;

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->cartoons;

// add a record
$document = array( "title" => "Calvin and Hobbes", "author" => "Bill Watterson" );
$collection->insert($document);

// add another record, with a different "shape"
$document = array( "title" => "XKCD", "online" => true );
$collection->insert($document);

// find everything in the collection
$cursor = $collection->find();

// iterate through the results
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    echo $document["title"] . "\n";
}

//List all databases
    $databases = $m->listDBs(); 
    echo ' <br> databases = <pre>';
    print_r($databases);
    $somedb=$m->$databases['databases'][0]['name'];


//List all collections from some database
    $collections =$somedb->listCollections();
    echo '<br> collections = <pre>  ';
    print_r($collections);
    $someCol=$somedb->$collections[0];


//List all documents from some collection  
$cursor = $someCol->find();
echo '<br> documents = <pre>  ';
foreach ( $cursor as $id => $value )
{
    echo "$id: ";
    var_dump( $value );
}
```

7) test mongodb from symfony3 project controller action:

```
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1\src\Pat\monBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

<?php

namespace Pat\monBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

use \MongoClient;

// http://127.0.0.1:8000/   - url to see the output of this action

/**
 * Default controller.
 *
 * @Route("/")
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
     //   phpinfo(); - should list mongo information like
     /*   MongoDB Support   enabled
Version     1.6.14
Streams Support     enabled
Supported Authentication Mechanisms
MONGODB-CR  enabled
SCRAM-SHA-1     enabled
MONGODB-X509    disabled
GSSAPI (Kerberos)   enabled
PLAIN 
      */

// connect
$m = new MongoClient();

 //the rest is the same as with index.php above in point 6.
```

B) packages installation for symfony3 to work with mongo.db

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\patmonS1\composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "doctrine/mongodb": "dev-master",
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.1",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0",
```

To be able to install the said packages, you have to check with phpinfo() what type of architecture you use (x86, or 64 ), what version of php you use, and if your php is thread-safe. Than download the corresponding mongo.dll from pecl
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.14/windows
, unzip it and copy to 
`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\ext` .
Add or uncomment the corresponding line in `C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\php.ini`. It should be lines:

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Restart apache.

Seems `php_mongo.dll` is used by SYmfony 3 packages (outdated!).
`php_mongodb.dll` one could use directly in php like `$m = new MongoClient();` described on http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

If i try to connect to mongodb like this `$m = new MongoClient();` from Controller action or from index.php located at `C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs`, it works perfectly as described below.